# html2canvas : remove empty space above the picture

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html2canvas

This makes me crazy. I simply would like html2canvas capture an image

I have that:

```
<div id="post" class="xx">Déposer</div>
<canvas width="500" height="200"></canvas>

<script type="text/javascript" src="html2canvas.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
   html2canvas($("#post"), {canvas: canvas}).then(function(canvas) {
        var img = canvas.toDataURL()
        window.open(img); 
   });
</script>
```

The result is this image:

[image: width and height not corresponding to the size of image]

The button appear at the bottom of the canvas, and I would like to keep only the button, any idea on how to get only the button ?

If I change the size of the canvas, then the result is like this:

[image]

and here is the code of the button :

```
<div id="post">
    <div style="float:left;background:url(g.png);width:21px;height:53px;"></div>
   <div id="c" style="float:left;background:url(c.png) repeat-x;height:53px;font-family:arial;text-shadow: -1px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);padding: 12px 20px;font-size: 20px;line-height: 24px;color: rgb(255, 255, 255);text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;text-decoration: none;">Déposer</div>
     <div style="float:left;background:url(d.png);width:21px;height:53px;"></div>
</div>
```

and the files :
[image: c.png]
[image: d.png]
[image: g.png]

which makes this button (no extra css in the page) :
[image]

Comment: In your js set the canvas size to the size of the image

Comment: already tried, please look the result above, the button disappear, I don't understand at all

Comment: can you throw you css in your example (i'm trying to do a local example and see if I can debug)

Comment: @SethMcClaine please see my update, there is no other css in the page, it's really strange..

Comment: Are you including any other js anywhere? (I've updated my answer with all of your updated information and still don't see the issue, there must be some external source causing the issue some how)

Comment: you're right, I'm removed all other content (php code) and the button appear like on your screen, but maybe there is a way to remove this padding? and how to "adapt" the size of the canvas to the size of the image?

Comment: You can create the `canvas` using JS and set the size to the size of `#post` instead of adding it through the html. (You may need to add a couple px to the canvas since html2canvas seems to add some padding)

Comment: yes good idea, but the width of the image can change depending the text of the button, but evthg will be solved if we can fix that, do you have any idea for this last thing?

Comment: Get the width right before you do the html2canvas. you should already have your content in by then, otherwise it wouldn't show up in the canvas anyways

Comment: strange, when I do alert($('#post').width());  I get width=1118 instead of the width of the button, I tihnk this is the width of the page, why it doesn't return the correct width? crazy..

Comment: @SethMcClaine just to let you know evthg is okay now, thanks a lot Seth!! :)

Comment: Good stuff! You're welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            canvas {
                border: solid red 1px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
<div id="post">
    <div style="float:left;background:url(g.png);width:21px;height:53px;"></div>
   <div id="c" style="float:left;background:url(c.png) repeat-x;height:53px;font-family:arial;text-shadow: -1px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);padding: 12px 20px;font-size: 20px;line-height: 24px;color: rgb(255, 255, 255);text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;text-decoration: none;">Déposer</div>
     <div style="float:left;background:url(d.png);width:21px;height:53px;"></div>
</div>
    <canvas width="500" height="200"></canvas>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="html2canvas.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
       html2canvas($("#post"), {canvas: canvas});

//.then is an invalid function for html2canvas
/*.then(function(canvas) {
            var img = canvas.toDataURL()
            window.open(img);
       });
*/
    </script>
</html>
```

Gives me the following results:

[image]

From that I would conclude

- html2canvas has a small amount of padding around where it adds the image to canvas
- You may have css on your button that may be causing the canvas to push it down farther than you would like